# Почему и от чего спасет мир красота?

Tags: литература

Все знают высказывание Ф.М. Достоевского "Красота спасет мир". Но не все вдумываются в смысл.
А вот интересно все-таки, что имел в виду Федор Михайлович? Красота чего? От чего спасет мир и, главное, каким образом? Мне все-таки кажется, что имелась в виду исключительно духовная красота - вот она действительно способна спасти мир. А то слабо представляю, как какая-нибудь моделька с одной извилиной собирается спасать мир))))

Answer (score 3):

Красота спасет мир

Из романа «Идиот» (1868) Ф. М. Достоевского (1821 — 1881).
Как правило, понимается буквально: вопреки авторскому толкованию понятия «красота».
В романе (ч. 3, гл. V) эти слова произносит 18-летний юноша Ипполит Терентьев, ссылаясь на переданные ему Николаем Иволгиным слова князя Мышкина и иронизируя над последним: «Правда, князь, что вы раз говорили, что мир спасет «красота»? Господа, — закричал он , громко всем, — князь утверждает, что мир спасет красота! А я утверждаю, что у него оттого такие игривые мысли, что он теперь влюблен.
 Господа, князь влюблен; давеча, только что он вошел, я в этом убедился. Не краснейте, князь, мне вас жалко станет. Какая красота спасет мир. Мне это Коля пересказал... Вы ревностный христианин? Коля говорит, что вы сами себя называете христианином.
Князь рассматривал его внимательно и не ответил ему». Ф. М. Достоевский был далек от собственно эстетических суждений — он писал о духовной красоте, о красоте души. Это отвечает Главному замыслу романа — создать образ «положительно прекрасного человека». Поэтому в своих черновиках автор называет Мышкина «князь Христос», тем самым себе напоминая, что князь Мышкин должен быть максимально схож с Христом — добротой, человеколюбием, кротостью, полным отсутствием эгоизма, способностью сострадать людским бедам и несчастьям. Поэтому «красота», о которой говорит князь (и сам Ф. М. Достоевский), — это есть сумма нравственных качеств «положительно прекрасного человека».[Здесь и продолжение](http://www.bibliotekar.ru/encSlov/10/161.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Красоту, которая спасет мир, не стоит делить на физическую и духовную. Человек тогда сможет   "спастись", то есть достичь определенного духовного развития и понять тайну своего бытия, когда научится видеть и понимать красоту окружающего мира, когда не будет противопоставлять себя и этот мир.

"Слышно, как трава растет", - такими  должны быть наше внимание и любовь и к природе, и к людям. Об этом писал, к примеру, выдающийся русский актер М. Чехов,считавший внимание важнейшим качеством человека. Такое внимательное мышление соединяет нас с всем, что мы видим вокруг, помогает понять  "творческую силу земли и всего живого". Именно тогда человек становится "так высок, так богат".

И уже от такого понимания сущего рождаются качества «положительно прекрасного человека», то есть "отсутствие эгоизма, способность сострадать людским бедам и несчастьям".

Answer (score 0):

..и что же есть Красота, как не Гармония..? ..точнее говоря, её выражение в том или ином виде.. будь то цвет или сочетание цветов.. или же звук, в чистом виде или  в виде аккорда.. или же ещё что связанное с тем или иным восприятием мира и нашим отношением к нему, выраженным через дела и слова.. чувствования и мысли.. ..причём, следует заметить, как внешне, так и внутренне.. взаимосвязано, так сказать..

..и да.. ..есть ещё и такое мнение, что не сама Красота, но "осознание Красоты спасёт мир" \Николай Константинович Рерих\ ..позволю себе несколько перефразировать одно высказывание, которое приведу ниже..

..Красота мира всегда находится в соответствии с Красотой духа, смотрящего на неё.. ..достаточно красивый духом ещё здесь, на земле, находит свой рай  \спасение\ -- уродливый \духом\ уже здесь имеет свой ад \погибель\

"Величие мира всегда находится в соответствии с величием духа, смотрящего на него. Достаточно возросший духом ещё здесь, на земле, находит свой рай - злой уже здесь имеет свой ад" \Генрих Гейне\

..спасибо за интересный вопрос, Fuchoin Kazuki..!

Comment: У кого пунктуации обучались, во всём красивый вы наш?

Comment: Почему "обучался"..? Учусь. Потому, в том числе, и здесь. Как-то так, добрый Вы мой собеседник @shampar.

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, у Достоевского, точнее у Князя Мышкина, "красота" понималась в значении "прекрасное". Такое значение приводит БТС Кузнецова и сопровождает его как раз этой цитатой из Д.:

> КРАСОТА... 2. Красивое, прекрасное. Какая к. кругом! Чувство красоты. К. жизни. * Красота спасёт мир (Достоевский).

Такое понимание не требует априорного разделения на "физическую" и "духовную" красоту.
Судя по всему, это значение первично в церковнославянском и, как следствие, в христианском (православном) контексте.

Остальное, по большому счету, уже литературоведческие изыски. Впрочем, я совсем не отрицаю тех выводов о душевной природе "красоты" (самого значения слова) у Достоевского, которые во множестве доступны в Интернете. Просто эти выводы пытаются сделать на основании мировоззрения героев, в то время как ситуация обратная. Именно это значение и является ключом (одним из) к пониманию христианской сущности мировоззрения Мышкина. Красота Христа спасла мир, Мышкин надеется, что и красота его самого и окружающих его людей также спасет мир. И жестоко ошибается.

В качестве бонуса - фрагмент лекции М. М. Дунаева.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sMIG9UKvGZs

К сожалению, он тоже идет "от обратного", объясняя значение фразы через христианскую мораль, а не наоборот. Но он-то и не ставит себе цель порассуждать о значении слова в русском языке, так что все объяснимо.